# Transforming initial data via SQL (pivot)

Tags: sql, performance

**Current format of data** -

```
a_date1 | a_date2 | a_date3 | b_date1 | b_date2 | b_date 3
```

**Expected output** -

```
Name | date1 | date 2 | date_3   
a | a_date1 | a_date2 | a_date3          
b | b_date1 | b_date2 | b_date3
```

There are millions of rows like this.

I have done this via "union all" but was wondering if there is an efficient way?

Thank you to this community for your help !

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`:

```
select 'a' as name, a_date1 as date1, a_date2 as date_2, a_date3 as date3
from t
union all
select 'b', b_date1 as date1, b_date2 as date_2, b_date3 as date3
from t;
```